# When should I save application data in WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime

In WinRT the Suspended event is supposed to be used to save application data. It is even written in the templates that come with Visual Studio. However when the user closes the app the Suspended event does not fire until 10 seconds later. If the user starts the application in the meantime the data is lost. How should I proceed in this case? I tried other events like page's NavigatedFrom but none of them fired.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this:

```
        Window.Current.Activated += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.WindowActivationState ==
                CoreWindowActivationState.Deactivated)
                ; //save data
        };
```

Comment: Activated event is raised when the app is being closed?

Comment: Yes... I know. You get the Activated event with a parameter saying it was actually... deactivated...

Comment: Iteresting. I'll try it tomorrow.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly. I even tried SpinWaiting in the event for several seconds to see if this will somehow block the user action but it seems to work just fine. Lets hope this is not a reason to be rejected submission in the marketplace.

Comment: @Stilgar Were you rejected from the store for using this technique?  It is something that I have been trying to figure out for some time now.

Comment: No. Passed the validation like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If an user close the App **he expects the App start from scratch next time**. But if user left the App to do another things **he expects to return back to the last action**.

If you force your app to save state even when user close the app:

***How could the user start the app from scratch in any time he wants?***

Comment: It is a game and there is a resume button for the last session. The user starts the app in a menu and can select a new game or resume. BTW even the Visual Studio templates say you should save data on this event.